# How to express this radical in terms of Golden Ratio?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, algebraic-manipulation

`(1/3)*Sqrt[(1/11)*(-3 - 2*Sqrt[5] + 3*Sqrt[178 + 82*Sqrt[5]])]`

$$
r=\frac{1}{3} \sqrt{-2 \sqrt{5}+3 \sqrt{82
   \sqrt{5}+178} \over 11}
$$
I need to express this radical in terms of the Golden ratio or in the powers of the Golden ratio. Please help me with this regard, thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that this is the right forum for your question? It seems all about the math, rather than Mathematica. Besides, there’s no code, and your expression is presented as an image, so you made it particularly difficult for anyone to consider helping you by not providing copy-pastable expressions...

Comment: Now I added the Mathematica expression. Please check.

Comment: `(1/3)*Sqrt[(1/11)*(-3 - 2*Sqrt[5] + 3*Sqrt[178 + 82*Sqrt[5]])] /. 
 Sqrt[5] -> 2*(\[Phi] + 1)`?

Comment: @user64494 I think your definition of `GoldenRatio` is off. How about `Simplify[(1/3) Sqrt[(1/11) (-3 - 2 Sqrt[5] + 3 Sqrt[178 + 82 Sqrt[5]])] /. Sqrt[5] -> 2 HoldForm@GoldenRatio - 1] // ReleaseHold` ?

Comment: @kirma:Thank you for the correction.

Comment: Maybe it would be useful to say that the number is the solution of the following equation `-77 + 891 x^4 - 132 GoldenRatio + x^2 (18 + 72 GoldenRatio) == 0`

Comment: @ShivamSharma Do you mean express it as $\sum_{k=0}^n a_k \phi^k$ for integer $a_k$'s?

Comment: I downvoted because the question is not clear despite several questions asked. What does "express this radical in terms of the Golden ratio or in the powers of the Golden ratio" mean exactly? Not clear if this is a math or Mathematica question. Will upvite if explations are given. @ShivamSharma

Comment: I am relatively inexperienced in Mathematica, I am an undergraduate student. I am learning to code. Thank you all for your useful answers.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do that completely automatically, but as @user64494 suggested, you can start by rewriting $\sqrt{5}$ to expressions involving $\phi$ (but you really should use `GoldenRatio` in Mathematica). This is my simplistic approach:

```
Simplify[
 (1/3) Sqrt[(1/11) (-3 - 2 Sqrt[5] + 3 Sqrt[178 + 82 Sqrt[5]])] /.
 Sqrt[5] -> 2 Hold@GoldenRatio - 1] // ReleaseHold // FullSimplify
```

> $$\frac{1}{3} \sqrt{\frac{1}{11}
>    \left(-4 \phi +6 \sqrt{41
>    \phi +24}-1\right)}$$

(... formatted with `TraditionalForm` or `TeXForm`.)

The trick here is to prevent `Simplify` from rewriting `GoldenRatio` to forms of the original equation with `Hold` (which is later released with `ReleaseHold`). The extra `FullSimplify` in the end is reduntant, but if there would be applicable simplifications for `GoldenRatio` available, it would be capable of performing them at this point without necessarily causing a mess.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful.